# SQL - Including whitespace in LIKE query for filtering content include swear words

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, whitespace, sql-like

I have a table of swear words in SQL Server and I use LIKE query to search texts for words in the table. I need a way to include whitespaces around the swear word in LIKE query, like this:

```
... LIKE '%{whitespace}SWEAR-WORD{whitespace}%';
```

Putting space around the swear word is not enough, because it can be a part of another normal word in my language (like 'inter' that is part of 'international' or 'pointer').

Another solution I've tried was using this:

```
... LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z]SWEAR-WORD[^a-zA-Z]%';
```

But that did not work for me.

Is there any way to do this? Or alternatively is there any solution other than LIKE query?

**Edit:** For better understanding, it's our current way to find swear-words:

We have a table named `Reviles` which has 2 columns (Id and Text) and contains restricted words and phrases. We use this query to find out whether a content has any of those restricted words and phrases:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * dbo.Reviles WHERE @Text LIKE '%' + dbo.Reviles.Text + '%')
  @IsHidden = 0
```

Note that this check is done before the content being inserted into its table. The code above is part of a stored procedure which gets information of a post and checks various things including swear words before inserting it.

Before we've stored restricted words like ' swear-word ' in the table, however this way we could not find and hide contents with swear words at the beginning or at the end of the line or contents which consists of only a swear word. For example:
`This is my content with a swear-word`
or
`Swear-word in my content`
or
`Swear-word`
So we decided to remove those spaces and store restricted words like 'swear-word'. But this causes some normal content to hide because some swear words can be part of another word which is normal (If we assume inter is a bad word, then pointer and international, etc. will be restricted).

Sorry for my bad English, I hope with this description, I've made it clear.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you just want a space before and after the swear word? You don't want to completely remove the swear words?

Comment: do you always have equal amount of spaces ?

Comment: This is hard to do. Because a swear word followed by punctuation wouldn't be found, but as you note there are many words (names particularly) that contain such a word (the "Scunthorpe Problem"). I suspect the limited capabilities of `LIKE` expressions with the expressiveness of Unicode means this is not soluble in pure SQL.

Comment: @TheSETJ Try with `LIKE '%[^a-z]swear-word[^a-z]%'`

Comment: SQL Server provides [full-text search for this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/query-with-full-text-search?view=sql-server-2017). You can't find words efficiently with `LIKE`, as it can't take advantage of indexes

Comment: Why would `interswearword` match `% swearword %`?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Can you post a solution as an answer with the full-text search for my problem? I'm kinda a newbie at my position and I don't know many capabilities available in SQL Server, by the way, I'm in a hurry to find a solution.
And I'll appreciate if you mention cons of using the full-text search too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to close your check statement in some chars and then compare:

**some data:**

```
declare @T table(stmt nvarchar(20))
insert into @T values ('inter'),('Inter.'),('My inter'),
('intermediate!'),('pointer '),('Good inter'),('inter inter inter')
```

**try this:**

```
select
    stmt as stmt,
    case
        when '.'+stmt+'.' like '%[^a-z]inter[^a-Z]%' then 1 else 0 end as [has inter]
from
    @T
```

**results:**

```
stmt                 has inter
-------------------- -----------
inter                1
Inter.               1
My inter             1
intermediate!        0
pointer              0
Good inter           1
inter inter inter    1
```

Comment: Adding those dots is clever. I've done a quick test and it works. However, I need to test it further. If it passes all of the tests, I'll mark your post as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit confuse what are u want to do, if u want to do like '{whitespace}swearword{whitespace}', then use `like '% inter %'` already work

but if u really have special requirement about filter, another way is enable SQL CLR, and Create Sql function from visualStudio and deploy to SQL Server. inside SQL function u can use Regular expression to return match or not.

1. Create SQL Databaase Project
2. Add SQL CLR(I use C#)
3. Add Code

   ```
   public partial class UserDefinedFunctions
   {
     [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction]
     public static SqlBoolean RegularMatch(string str, string pattern)
     {
       var regex = new Regex(pattern);
       return new SqlBoolean (regex.IsMatch(str));
     }
   }
   ```
4. Public to SQL Server

Sorry I'm not good at format this.

Comment: We had '% swear-word %' before. The problem is if the swear word shows up as a single word or at the first of the line, or at the end of the line, this pattern can't find that.

Comment: @TheSETJ then u can try this CLR Regular solution.

Comment: I have remote access to the database, and can't deploy anything (or at least don't know how). But I appreciate your help. By the way, to expand my knowledge, I'm interested to know more. Can you please give me any video link including an example of this method or anything that deeply explain it (I mean using CLR with SQL Server database)?

Comment: @TheSETJ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-user-defined-functions/clr-scalar-valued-functions?view=sql-server-2017